# How can i sort a list of lists on the basis of score value

Tags: python

I have a list similar to

> [['abbc', 23.0], ['zaab', 32.0]]

How can I sort my list of lists on the basis of score value.

```
list1=[]
for _ in range(int(input("enter no of students"))):
    list=[]
    name = input("enter name")
    score = float(input("enter score"))
    list. Append(name)
    list. Append(score)
    list1.append(list)

print(sorted(list1))
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Use `sorted` with a key: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For illustration lets say that your original list is- lst=  [['zaab', 32.0], ['abbc', 23.0]]-then you can use the following code to get the desired list i.e. lst1 =[['abbc', 23.0], ['zaab', 32.0]].

```
dct=dict(lst)
lst1 = sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
lst1=[list(i) for i in lst1]
lst1
```

Your out put will be:

```
[['abbc', 23.0], ['zaab', 32.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to sort list of list example

```py
list = [["abbc", 32.0],  ["zaab", 23.0]]
```

All you need to do is

```py
list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])

print(list)
```

result

```py
[ ["zaab", 23.0], ["abbc", 32.0]]
```